# Find the spectral distribution of a metallic reflection given electron configuration

Tags: metals, radiometry

If I have the electron configuration for a metallic element, how do I find the spectral distribution of its specular reflection?

For example, for gold (2,8,18,32,18,1) I should get a greater distribution in longer wavelengths.

---

Since this is for programming purposes, a rough estimate is okay, although the ability to input alloys would be even better.

Comment: You don't. The electronic configuration of metal atoms has very little to do with the optical properties of the bulk metal. For "programming purposes" I would go with tabulated data and simple plasma frequency models. See e.g. "Optical properties of the metals Al, Co, Cu, Au, Fe, Pb, Ni, Pd, Pt, Ag, Ti and W in the infrared and far infrared" by M.A. Ordal et al.. Also take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasmon.

Comment: It actually does matter. What Gives Gold that Mellow Glow? See https://www.fourmilab.ch/documents/golden_glow/

Comment: @mmesser314 - the problem is that Cu and Au have very similar optical properties, a point often overlooked in the rush to say something is 'special' about gold. It isn't, really, all that special in the context of band structure.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to do something unusual and answer this by evaluating the first three comments above.  First, CuriousOne is pragmatically correct.  Knowing the electronic configuration is a long way from enabling you to determine the behavior of specular reflection of visible light from a bulk metal.  The reason is that the absorption capabilities of bulk metals depends upon very detailed knowledge of the electronic states, knowledge that is very difficult to obtain theoretically.  Hence as CuriousOne suggest you are better off using experimental data.

The reason for this is made clear by the link provided in mmesser314's comment.  Not only are you dealing with a complex many body problem, but for an atom as heavy as gold you can't even rely upon the Schrodinger equation (Hartree-Fock approach) for your calculations because the electrons are moving at a significant fraction of the speed of light.  The details provided in the link were, no doubt, obtained within a relativistic Hartree-Fock approach where the Dirac equation was used for the computations.

Finally, Jon Custer's comment reminds us that even a relativistic Hartree-Fock approach is not the final answer because it neglects the effects of atoms being bound within a bulk material which may be considerable.